# Display Array of data in Twig

Tags: arrays, symfony, for-loop, twig

I would like to display the following array of data in twig:

```
array:7 
  0 => []
  1 => "Q4(2017)"
  2 => "Q1(2018)"
  3 => "Q2(2018)"
  4 => "Q3(2018)"
  5 => "Q4(2018)"
  6 => "Q1(2019)"
]
```

I tried to display the above array of data in Symfony Twig as following but it returned error.  Could you please advise?

```
{% for key, value in arrayList %} 

  <br>{{ value }}<br>

{% endfor %}
```

I expect the results as following but it returned errors

```
Q4(2017)
Q1(2018)
Q2(2018)
Q3(2018)
Q4(2018)
Q1(2019)
```

Comment: The value at index 0 is an array, thus can not be printed out

Comment: Thank you for your comment  I fixed the array as you suggested, however it returned nothing, I got a blank page.  Please help. Thanks

Comment: Should work as is though. See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/zcj21j). Try enabling debug mode for `twig`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass key and value as parameters.

```
{% for value in arrayList %} 

  <br>{{ value }}<br>

{% endfor %}
```